# How to return values from option tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-select

I am trying to return some information from [flightradar24.com](http://flightradar24.com) using jsoup.
The information I need is displayed in a drop-down box.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.flightradar24.com/").get();
    Elements radarCode = doc.getElementsByTag("option");

    for(int i=0; i<radarCode.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(radarCode.get(i).text() + "\n");
    }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am trying to return all radar information that is displayed. If you go onto the website and click on filter over to the left hand side, a box will display. Find the radio button that says "Radar" and then it should show a drop down box. This drop down box is the one I am try to get the information from.

Comment: It seems that this site may be generated dynamically with JS. In that case Jsoup will not be able to handle it. You will need to use some web driver like Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I think Pshemo's comment is correct.   JSoup is great for static site, but the minute there is a need to get data generated from javascript, you need to upgrade to another solution.   There are many good ones, pulling in a headless browser like HTMLUnit or PhantomJS, or Selenium (which can tie into a headless or standard browser like Firefox).   Depending on your project, I'd start with HTMLUnit or Selenium with HTMLUnit.